# Bind click event to selector with knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, jquery-events

I have searched and I have tried different selectors but I can't figure this out.  I am following a tutorial, but I am not getting a result.

The `click` event doesn't seem to be binding to the dynamically generated `div` section `'.person-brief'`?  There is no `click` event associated with it.  I tried `.live()` also, but that seems to have been deprecated.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

**person.js model**

```
var gotoDetails = function (selectedPerson) {
    if (selectedPerson && selectedPerson.id()) {
        var url = '#/persondetail/' + selectedPerson.id();
        router.navigateTo(url);
    }
};

var viewAttached = function (view) {
    bindEventToList(view, '.person-brief', gotoDetails); 
};

var bindEventToList = function (rootSelector, selector, callback, eventName) {
    var eName = eventName || 'click'; 
    $(rootSelector).on(eName, selector, function () { 
        var ser = ko.dataFor(this); 
        callback(ser);
        return false;
    });
};

var vm = {
    people: people,
    title: 'people demo',
    viewAttached: viewAttached
};
return vm;
```

**person.html view**

```html
<section id="person-view" class="view">
    <header>
        <a class="btn btn-info btn-force-refresh pull-right"
           data-bind="click: refresh" href="#"><i class="icon-refresh"></i>Refresh</a>
        <h3 class="page-title" data-bind="text: title"></h3>
        <div class="article-counter">
            <address data-bind="text: people().length"></address>
            <address>found what</address>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section  class="view-list" data-bind="foreach: people">
        <article class="article-left-content">
            <div class="person-brief" title="Go to person details">
                <small data-bind="text: firstname" class="right"></small>
                <small data-bind="text: lastname"></small>
            </div>
        </article>
    </section>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With KnockoutJS you should use [the `click` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) (or alternatively [the `event` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html)), not use jQuery to manually manipulate the DOM.

Something like this becomes your code:

```
var vm = {
    people: people,
    title: 'people demo',
    viewAttached: viewAttached
};

vm.myHandler = function (person) { 
  goToDetails(person);
  return false;
};
```

And since `myHandler` is so simple you might as well inline the `goToDetails` code, which has access to `vm` from its closure.

You bind in the view like this:

```html
<div class="person-brief" data-bind="click: $root.myHandler">
...
</div>
```

A general tip: do a tutorial on *either* jQuery, *or* KnockoutJS. If you take the latter, try to use as little is possible jQuery (which is usually quite possible), most notably don't use jQuery to manipulate the DOM (except in custom binding handlers and after-render functions).

Comment: thanks, I was following tutorial by John Pappa and figure that was the best practice so I didn't look at other methods, probably outdated.  This is much simpler than what it was...thanks much.